# Use a .vue file in the browser via fetch

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a chrome extension, I can make an xhr/fetch request for a file (`template.vue`).

is it possible to instantiate a new Vue instance using the contents of that file?

For example:

**template.vue**

```
<template>
  <div> hello {{name}}</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
     name: "bob"
  })
}
</script>
```

**content_script.js**

```
const response = await fetch("template.vue");
const text = await response.body();
const vue = new Vue.extend({
   something: text
})
```

Comment: uses `*.vue` files may be possible, but your plugin have to implement one `vue-loader` and `webpack` to build it. One possible better approach will be pass one json like `{template: 'something', data: function () {}, ...}`

Comment: Not exactly `fetch`, but [`http-vue-loader`](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader) can load a Vue component from a URL without a build step. However, [it's not meant for production](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader#notes).